# Confusion with Taylor series of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know $e^{-1/x^2}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$, is an example of a smooth function that cannot be represented all the coefficients are $0$, but I am curious about the Lagrange remainder. Doesn't the remainder still approach $0$ because $n!$ grows faster than any derivative of $e^{−1/x^2}$. So in that case, since the remainder goes to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, that would imply this function is represented by the Taylor expansion right? Am I misunderstanding the remainder theorem?

Comment: Why is it so clear that $f^{(n)}(x)$ with some fixed $x>0$ grows slower than $n!$?

Comment: Any derivative of f(x) with x=0 is 0. Hence, It grows slower.

Comment: In the Lagrange remainder you do not evalate the derivative at $0$ but at a point between $0$ and $x$ (which may not be $0$ if $x \neq 0$).

Comment: And when N goes to infinity the derivative is justo a number, the factorial is infinite

Comment: But you take the $N$th derivative, and vary $N$. It will be a sequence which may grow fast with respect to $N$.

Comment: You will have as the $n$th remainder $$
\frac{{f^{(n)} (\xi )}}{{n!}}x^n  = e^{ - 1/\xi ^2 } \left( {\frac{x}{\xi }} \right)^n \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^k \frac{{a(n,k)}}{{n!}}\frac{1}{{\xi ^k }}} 
$$ with $a(n,k)$ as in https://oeis.org/A136656 and $0<\xi <x$. Why would this go to $0$ for large $n$ and $x \neq 0$?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then, I cant assure that the remainder goes to 0, right?

Comment: Yes, in fact it cannot go to zero unless $x=0$, because your function is not analytic at the origin.

Comment: Ok,great. Thanks.